# ProgressDialog near application label

Tags: android, progressdialog, progress

I noticed that some applications have ProgressDialog near application label which i marked with red circle in the image below -
[image]

does somebody know how can i get ProgressDialog there?

Comment: Are you talking about the three dots that when you click they show options such as "settings" and such?

Comment: no, i'm talking about this - http://i.stack.imgur.com/bdrWh.png

Comment: Oh, that's a `ProgressDialog`. A `spinner` is a dropdown menu

Comment: my bad, just edited this post! :)

Comment: its not in the dropdown menu .Normally the bar u marked there is accessible in manifest . I dont how to get spinner there ,i wil come back to u with result

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the so called [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). This UI concept allows developers to place their menu and contextual information regarding to the currently displayed screen in a separate bar at the top, including the indeterminate progress indicator you mentioned. Natively, this bar isn't available on older android versions, but there is an excellent library that allows you to use the action bar and still target older versions: [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

You can take a look at the capabilities of the action bar with the [ActionBarSherlock Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos)